# How to store looped numbers in array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a program that loops through each row of data in a sheet. The rows contain numbers. I want to store the all the numbers found in an array variable then compare each to the highest and lowest.

But I don't know how automatically to store numbers in an array.

Comment: If your final purpose is to find the maximum number in a row then `Application.Max(.Rows(i))` should suffice. Same for `Application.Min`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store them in an array, but check for the smallest/biggest on the fly!

```
Sub test()

dim max As Double, min As Double
dim r As Range, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1","A10")' Set this to the appropriate range
min = rng(1).Value
max = rng(1).Value

For each r in rng

If r.Value > max Then

max = r.Value

Elseif r.Value < min Then

min = r.Value

End If
Next r

Range("B1").Value = max ' store where ever you want
Range("B2").Value = min 'same as above

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways to get the minimum and maximum value in a row of blanks, text and numbers but here is an example of collecting the numbers in a row into a variant array.

```
Sub minmax()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long, vNUMs As Variant
    Dim mn As Double, mx As Double

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For r = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

            'you can do this the easy way
            mx = Application.Max(.Rows(r))
            mn = Application.Min(.Rows(r))
            Debug.Print mn & " to " & mx

            'or the hard way
            n = 0
            ReDim vNUMs(Application.Count(.Rows(r)) - 1)
            For c = 1 To .Cells(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                If IsNumeric(.Cells(r, c)) And Not IsEmpty(.Cells(r, c)) Then
                    vNUMs(n) = .Cells(r, c).Value2
                    n = n + 1
                    If n > UBound(vNUMs) Then Exit For
                End If
            Next c

            mx = -2 ^ 20
            mn = 2 ^ 20
            For n = LBound(vNUMs) To UBound(vNUMs)
                If vNUMs(n) < mn Then mn = vNUMs(n)
                If vNUMs(n) > mx Then mx = vNUMs(n)
            Next n
            Debug.Print mn & " to " & mx
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```